# problems in connection of windows server to unix server

Tags: linux, vb.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, http-status-code-401

Migrated a web application from windows 2003 server to windows 2012 server.

The problem occurs when a part of code has to login to a linux server and perform some commands over there.

Code is

```
sResponse = obj.RunSSH_Resp(anotherObj.Server, 
My.Settings.UNIX_FUNC_LOGIN.ToString, 
My.Settings.UNIX_FUNC_PASSWORD.ToString, sCmd, False, 120, "StartTag")
```

while this code was performing ok on the old server, it seems we have not done some configurations on the new server, that why the windows server is not able to communicate with linux server.

I was able to ping successfully the linux server from windows server, but when I tried to open linux drives (as they are SAMBA drives shared) I was not able to open them.

**Edit:** I believe there is some problem with the permissions in the web application  IIS manager. Can you please tell what should be the correct IIS configuration to enable web application communicate with a linux server.

**Edit 2:** The following code returns

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

```
Public Function RunSSH_Resp(ByVal i_sServer As String, ByVal i_sLogin As String, ByVal i_sPassword As String, _
               ByVal i_sCommand As String, Optional ByVal i_bEscapeCmd As Boolean = True, _
               Optional ByVal i_lTimeout As Long = 20, Optional ByVal i_sStartTag As String = "") As String

            Dim oWebRequest As WebRequest
            Dim oRequestStream As Stream
            Dim oStreamWriter As StreamWriter
            Dim oWebResponse As WebResponse
            Dim oResponseStream As Stream
            Dim oStreamReader As StreamReader
            Dim sWebSSHUrl As String = My.Settings.WEBSSH_URL.ToString

            Dim sEscapeCmd As String = "y"
            If Not i_bEscapeCmd Then sEscapeCmd = "n"

            Dim sResponseText As String = ""

            Dim sFormData As String
            sFormData = "server=" & i_sServer & "&login=" & i_sLogin & "&password=" & i_sPassword & _
                        "&command=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(i_sCommand) & "&timeout=" & i_lTimeout & _
                        "&starttag=" & HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(i_sStartTag) & "&escapecmd=" & sEscapeCmd

            ' Create a new WebRequest
            ' if working in a separate environment, then call the server by name, otherwise localhost (this should not be done to prevent login and password passing in network)
            Try
                oWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(sWebSSHUrl)
                oWebRequest.Method = "POST"
                oWebRequest.ContentLength = sFormData.Length
                oWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                oWebRequest.Timeout = i_lTimeout * 1000
                'oWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = True
                'oWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = True
                'oWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
                oRequestStream = oWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

                'send the request       
                oStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(oRequestStream)
                oStreamWriter.Write(sFormData)
                oStreamWriter.Flush()
                oStreamWriter.Close()
                oRequestStream.Close()

                ' Get the response
                oWebResponse = oWebRequest.GetResponse()
                oResponseStream = oWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
                oStreamReader = New StreamReader(oResponseStream)

                sResponseText = oStreamReader.ReadToEnd()
                oStreamReader.Close()
                oResponseStream.Close()
                oWebResponse.Close()

            Catch ex As Exception
                oWebRequest = Nothing
                oRequestStream = Nothing
                oStreamWriter = Nothing
                oWebResponse = Nothing
                oResponseStream = Nothing
                oStreamReader = Nothing
                Return ex.Message

        End Try
End Function
```

Comment: This question needs more information.  What sort of object is `anotherObj`? What about `obj`? Have you verified that it's possible to login manually to the linux box from the new windows server? (because it could be network/firewall rules).  What is the error message?

Comment: @GregHNZ I have edited the question. i think it is network/firewall rules, can you please let me know how they can be configured.